# How to store export larger data to CSV in PHP?

Tags: mysql, export

I want to export thousands of records, let's say I have 165K records to export to CSV. What I am doing is to fetch all the records and put them in an array and then use the `fputcsv()` function to export it to CSV. But doing so crashes my page. I have set `set_time_limit(0)` as well but it doesn't work either. Here is how I am doing it:

```
QUERY-> SELECT s.id, 
               s.name, 
               s.email, 
               s.postcode, 
               s.dob
        FROM `subscribers_table` s
        WHERE s.status=1";

while(row = fetch..) {
    $myarray[] = array_data
}

$fp = fopen(..);
foreach($array as $key => $value)
    fputcsv($fp, $value);           
fclose($fp);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What error do you have? It seems it is memory overflow. Set 'memory_limit' directive in php.ini to larger value.

Also what you want to do can be done by MySQL alone:

```
SELECT s.id, 
       s.name, 
       s.email, 
       s.postcode, 
       s.dob
   INTO OUTFILE 'c:/somefile.csv'
   COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ' '
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   FROM `subscribers_table` s;
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply but I don't have the root privileges therefore I can't export it using MySQL. I will increase the memory limit and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution what you do,
. my solution is get limiting amount of data from db process it and then get back to amount of data 
as simply happens in pagination.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Considering this approach it will take a lot of time to export thousands of records. Do you think this approach is suitable?

Comment: yes it will take time , but it is not memory exhausting.like if you do ini set and increase memory but if record will be more then then it will again crash. even i made a class that will use less memory and write your data in multiple csv, as per your need.but i don't have a way to share.

Comment: hello. Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your support. I have used this approach. I wrote a cron job that fetches records from database and directly saves into the file, instead of putting into an array. This way my program does not crash and successfully generates the file. Thanks again.

Comment: you can get multipartcsv class from here https://github.com/developerck/multipartCSV.git, and if it helped you then mark it answered.